# Ignoring the blank spaces at the end of a file

Tags: c++, file, io

Is there a way to add a line at the end of a file even if there are blank lines at the end of it? Here's an example code:

```
 void add(fstream &inputfile, int x, int y)
    {
        inputfile.clear();
        inputfile.seekg(0, ios::end);
        while(??)                             //while last line is blank space
            inputfile.seekg(-1, ios::end);    //go back one line
        inputfile << x << "\t" << y << endl;  //when while's finished add the new one
        inputfile.seekp(0);
    }
```

In order to accomplish this output:

```
Input file:
1 2
2 3

Wrong output file:
1 2
2 3


3 4

Correct output file:
1 2
2 3
3 4
```

Is it possible to be done this way? What should be put inside that while loop? The code should be working even if there aren't any blank spaces so we have to use a while statement instead of a simple if one. If it can't be done this way do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to just before the end of the file. Then use a loop that peeks at the next character (reads it without advancing). If it's a newline it goes back a character and repeats the loop. When you get to the last non-newline character, seek ahead 2 bytes, to skip over that character and the newline.

```
inputfile.seekg(-1, ios::end);
while(inputfile.peek() == '\n') {
    inputfile.seekg(-1, ios::cur);
}
inputfile.seekg(2, ios::cur);
```